# JQuery bind click event to checkboxes

Tags: jquery, bind

Here's a basic view of what my html looks like:

```
<form>
  <div id="part1">
     // some html form elements including checkboxes
  </div>
  <div id="part2">
    // more html code with more checkboxes
  </div>
  <div id=part2">
     // data table with numerous checkboxes built dynamically
  </div
</form>
```

What I need to do is bind the `.click()` event to the checkboxes in part 1, 2, and 3 seperately.  I've tried this `$('#part1:checkbox').click(...)` but that didn't work.  If I use `$("form :checkbox").click(...)` same click event is bound to all checkboxes and not just one set.  How would I seperate these?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need a space to separate the descendant selector:

```
$('#part1 :checkbox').click(function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

To increase performance, you might wanna use this:

```
$('#part1 input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: ugh.. the difference a space makes mahalos

Comment: @Jared - `input[type=checkbox]` is a valid CSS selector. When possible, jQuery will pass the selector along to [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which is far more efficient than jQuery's own implementation of `:checkbox`.

Comment: and how to get text of selected checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

Or you give same class name for all checkboxes and give the corresponding div ID for the checkbox also, so you can use the following code,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkall" id="part1">Part 1
```

and your script goes like this.

```
$('.checkall').click(function () {
if (this.checked == false) {
$("." + $(this).attr("id")).hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and this StackOverflow page is the first answer I stumbled upon, but wasn't really satisfied with it.   I found this article https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-checkbox-checked/ with a better solution.

```
$('input[name="subscribe"]').on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $('input[name="email"]').show();
    } 
    else {
        $('input[name="email"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#part1 input:checkbox').click(...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/